# JQuery Mobile Phonegap Android App - dropdowns have duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, html

I am making an Android app using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap but have run into a problem. The use case is as follows:

- Screen 1. Choose to browse a list of businesses or a list of businesses that allow bookings to be made.
- Screen 2. Choose a type of business, e.g. Doctors or Dentists
- Screen 3. Choose a location from a drop-down to find these types of businesses in
- Screen 4. Select one of the businesses.

My problem is when a user gets to the screen where they can select a business and then decides to go back and change the type of business, when they are then presented with the select a location screen for a second time, the locations are all duplicated. If they repeat this process then there are three entries of each location in the drop-down menu, and so on.

(see the screenshots at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol382.jpg if they might help).

The locations are all retrieved using JSON data returned from a database query. I have tried emptying all the variables once they have been used to populate the drop-down so that the next time the page is encountered they will not have data in them. I have also tried forcing the drop-down to be empty using the jQuery .empty function but still for some reason the drop-down has duplicate entries. The only time when the drop-down returns to normal is if the user goes back to the main page and goes through the process again. This makes me think that the data is being cached or else something on the main page causes everything the be started from scratch again

Any ideas why a drop-down would have all its entries duplicated each time the page is arrived at. Let me know if there is something I could provide to help understand the problem.

**EDIT :**
Showing the code that writes to the dropdown select menu:

```
$('#categorySearch').live('pageshow', function(event) { 
theWindow = "categorysearch.html";

// //different ways of removing the options from within a select box, tried using them all since some didn't seem to function correctly but to no avail
// $('#search1').children().remove();
// $('#search1 option').remove();
// $('#search1').empty();
// $('#search1').html("");

// //different ways of removing the options from within a select box, tried using them all since some didn't seem to function correctly but to no avail
// $('#search2').children().remove();
// $('#search2 option').remove();
// $('#search2').empty();
// $('#search2').html("");

//variables for the necessary parameters to send to the query
var id = getUrlVarsCategorySearch()["id"];
var getCats = "";
var getParams = "";

//check which type of listing is being requested
if(submitBtn == "Book+Appointment")
{
    getCats = "Bookable+Listings";
}
else
{
    getCats = "All+Listings";
}

//the $_GET[] parameters to send
getParams = "?cat=" + id + "&submitBtn=" + getCats;

$('#search1').empty();

//add in empty option to tell user to select a county
$('#search1').append('<option value="" selected="selected">Select a county</option>\n');//add empty first option so the user will always have to change

//request state locations from the database
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getlocations.php' + getParams, function(data)
{
    var stateLocations = data.items;

    //fill the search box with these locations
    $.each(stateLocations, function(index, stateLocation)
    {
        $('#search1').append('<option value="' + stateLocation.state + '">' + stateLocation.state + '</option>\n');
    });
    //trying to empty any variables once used so there shouldn't be data in them the next time the page is loaded
    stateLocations = null;
    data = null;

}).error(function(){ window.location = './error.html'; });

$("#search1").selectmenu("refresh", true);

$('#search1 option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

**EDIT #2 :**
Added sample HTML code

```
<div id="categorySearch" data-role="page">
<form action="./linklist.html" method="get">
    <div id="searchBox1">
        <label for="search1">Located in:</label>
        <select name="search1" id="search1">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<p align="center">
    <input id="findBtn" type="submit" data-icon="search" value="Find" data-inline="true" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input id="clearBtn" type="reset" data-icon="delete" value="Clear" data-inline="true"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your JSON data being duplicated (appended) instead of overwriting the previous data?

Comment: Try posting the code as well so that others who come to see the issues, can get a better idea on how your idea is implemented. Just my 2 cents.